# Problem with return statement, it return undefined always

Tags: javascript

## I wanted something to be returned as output but not able to.

```
function arrsort(arr){
 return arr.sort(function(a, b){return a - b});
 }
const binarySearch=(arr,num,start,end)=>{
 arr=arrsort(arr);
 start=0;
 end=arr.length;
 var mid = Math.floor(end / 2);
 if (arr[mid] === num) {
    return true;
 } else if (arr[mid] < num && end > 1) {
    binarySearch(arr.splice(mid, Number.MAX_VALUE), num,start,end);
 } else if (arr[mid] > num && end > 1) {
    binarySearch(arr.splice(start, mid), num,start, end);
 } else {
        return false;
 }
  }
```

### I expected the output as true or false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some more return statements before calling the same function again.

And while you return for every `true` `if` statement, you could omit `else`.

```
function arrsort(arr) {
    return arr.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a - b;
    });
}

const binarySearch = (arr, num, start, end) => {
    arr = arrsort(arr);
    start = 0;
    end = arr.length;
    var mid = Math.floor(end / 2);
    if (arr[mid] === num) {
        return true;
    } 
    if (arr[mid] < num && end > 1) {
        return binarySearch(arr.splice(mid, Number.MAX_VALUE), num, start, end);
    } 
    if (arr[mid] > num && end > 1) {
        return binarySearch(arr.splice(start, mid), num, start, end);
    } 
    return false;
}
```